# Django: join on DateTimeField

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

How to join two models on DateTimeField?

```
class ExchangeRate(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(...)
    usd_rub = models.DecimalField(...)

class LedgerEntry(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(...)
    date = models.DateTimeField(...)
    amount = models.DecimalField(...)
```

Here is an example of what I want. Note that records in ExchangeRate table have arbitrary date and time (there're not corresponding to the dates in LedgerEntry table). It's okay to join ExchangeRates just on date or hours (it is safe to ignore minutes, seconds, etc.)

```
        ExchangeRate                        LedgerEntry            
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––-    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––---------
|      Date     |  USD_RUB |    | account |      Date     | Amount |
|---------------|----------|    |–––––––––|---------------|--------|
| 29 Nov, 14:15 |  100.00  |    |    13   | 29 Nov, 14:40 |  10.0  |
| 29 Nov, 14:04 |  200.00  |    |    37   | 29 Nov, 14:45 |  11.0  |
| 29 Nov, 13:51 |  150.00  |    |    19   | 01 Oct, 10:32 |  12.0  |
| ............. | .........|    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––---------
| 01 Oct, 10:23 |  500.00  |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––-

                           Join result                             
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––-------------------------------------
| account |      Date     | Amount |  USD_RUB | USD_RUB amount |
|–––––––––|---------------|--------|----------|----------------|
|    13   | 29 Nov, 14:40 |  10.0  |  100.00  |    1000.0      |
|    37   | 29 Nov, 14:45 |  11.0  |  100.00  |    1100.0      |
|    19   | 01 Oct, 10:32 |  12.0  |  500.00  |    6000.0      |
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––-------------------------------------
```

I understand that I can just query all these objects from the database and "join" them in Python. There are thousands records in the database, so this is really inefficient, as it produces enormous amount of single select statements when looking for a corresponding exchange rate for a ledger entry.

Answer (score 0):

At first I was thinking to make a left join using raw SQL, but I've figured out a solution using `extra()`:

```
referral_profits = LedgerEntry.objects.filter(
    balance=request.user.balance,
    reason=LedgerEntry.REASON_DEBIT
).extra(
    select={ 'usd_value': r'''
        SELECT usd_rub
        FROM stats_exchangerate
        WHERE 
            date_trunc('hour', billing_ledgerentry.date) = 
            date_trunc('hour', stats_exchangerate.date)
        LIMIT 1
        '''
    },
)
for x in referral_profits:
    print(x, x.usd_value, x.date)
```

Please note that `date_trunc` is a Postgres-speficic function.

EDIT: It works, but it's terribly inefficient. Looks like the last resort is to use pure SQL?